# Какая нотификация посылается окну при установке/удалении раскладки клавиатуры?

Tags: winapi, c++

Чтобы не дергать `GetKeyboardLayoutList` постоянно...

---

Сейчас делаю хуком (см. ответ от userx), если есть более легковесное решение с помощью сообщений - прошу поделиться знаниями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для отслеживания изменений в наборе доступных раскладок есть специальный хук [HSHELL_LANGUAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644991(v=vs.85).aspx). Вам надо установить его, чтобы получать уведомления при добавлении или удалении раскладок.

Другой возможный вариант - это работа с текстовыми службами.

Comment: Сообщений не посылается?

Comment: Сообщений не посылается.